# Adding space between characters of a string containing special accented character

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to add space between the characters of a string such as the following: `'abakə̃tə̃'`?

The usual `' '.join('abakə̃tə̃')` approach returns `'a b a k ə ̃ t ə ̃'`, I am looking for `'a b a k ə̃ t ə̃'`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with a pattern that matches a word character optionally followed by an non-word character (which matches an accent):

```
import re
s = 'abakə̃tə̃'
print(' '.join(re.findall(r'\w\W?', s)))
```

For Python 3.7+, where zero-width patterns are allowed in `re.split`, you can use a lookahead and a lookbehind pattern split the string at positions that are followed by a word character and preceded by any character:

```
print(' '.join(re.split(r'(?<=.)(?=\w)', s)))
```

Both of the above would output:

```
a b a k ə̃ t ə
```